# <h:commandButton> not firing the action method

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I have a nested `<h:form>`, and inside the inner most `<h:form>` I have a `<h:commandButton>` like this,

```
<h:commandButton value="Next" actionListener="#{billController.saveFiles}"\>

public void saveFiles(ActionEvent event){
 //code
}
```

But this method is not getting invoked by clicking the action button.
Can anyone give a solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

Just stop nesting forms. Nested forms are [invalid](http://validator.w3.org) in HTML. You should never nest HTML `<form>` elements.  As JSF is merely a HTML code generator, it's also not different from JSF side on. You should never nest JSF `<h:form>` components as well.

The browser behavior on nested forms is unspecified.

Answer (score 1):

Can you post your whole jsp page? If button is not inside `<h:form>` tag it wont call action method